# Free and paid tiers for AppExchange app

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, 2gp, feature-management

Is it possible for a paid AppExchange app to charge 0 USD for Basic subscription and > 0 USD for Premium? And activate the Premium subscription using the FeatureManagement functionality. What are the disadvantages of this approach compared to splitting into two apps (free and paid)?

Answer (score 0):

Please find below answers to your questions to the best of my knowledge :

*Is it possible for a paid AppExchange app to charge 0 USD for Basic subscription and > 0 USD for Premium?*

- This is essentially known as a **Freemium** model of pricing where your app is free to use upto a certain limit and chargeable afterwards.
- The payment can be based on parameters like consumption, frequency, any data limit etc
- Please refer this trailhead for detailed info - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/appexchange-pricing-strategy-for-partners/create-pricing-plan

*Can we activate the Premium subscription using the FeatureManagement functionality?*

- I have never tried this but Salesforce provides a good doc describing your use case [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/fma_lmo_to_subscriber.htm)
- Also , using feature management you can track users preferences & metrics. More info is provided [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/fma_subscriber_to_lmo.htm)

*What are the disadvantages of this approach compared to splitting into two apps (free and paid)?*

- Configuring & setting up pricing strategy would be time consuming.

I don't see many disadvantages in single app with multiple pricing tiers.

On the contrary , having two separate apps would pose challenges for customers to upgrade from free to paid versions.
Additionally , 2 separate apps will need separate code bases which will increase maintenance as well.(Essentially , duplicating efforts for every new release)